# Asteroids game c++ inertia

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my asteroid keep moving once I press a button.

```
void Ship::applyThrust()

{

   _v.setX(_v.getX() - sin(2 * M_PI * (_angle / 360)) * 2.5); 

   _v.setY(_v.getY() + cos(2 * M_PI * (_angle / 360)) * 2.5); 

}
```

This is the formula I have to help my ship move.

The _v.setX and _vsetY updates the X and Y position

The M_PI is just 3.14.

The _angle is how much of a rotation I set with my left and right arrow keys and

The 2.5 is how many frames per I want it to move

My ship is moving just fine, the problem is that I'm trying to simulate space inertia and have my ship continue moving.

Any ideas on how would be the logic for this?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to simulate progress of time. Applying thrust (aka acceleration) should increase velocity, not position. Once the body has non-zero velocity, its position would keep changing by that velocity times time passed.

Comment: thanks for the insight Since the beginning of this project I'm confusing the position with velocity.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your game loop, you'll need a function that updates the position of the ship based on its x and y velocity.  You're close in getting the new x and y coordinates of your ship, but you don't account for the velocity of the ship.  When you apply thrust, get the x and y components of your *velocity*, not your new position.  You'll have an additional function to update position which should be called within the game loop at a timed interval - e.g. every time you update the frame.  So your *applyThrust* function should actually update your ship's velocity.  That means you'll need to add variables to your *Ship* class for your ship's position and your ship's velocity if you don't already have them.  I'm breaking out the components of position and velocity for simplicity, but you'll probably want to store them in a vector for clarity:

```
class Ship 
{
    private float xpos, ypos; // current position of your ship
    private float velocityX, velocityY; // current velocity of your ship
}
```

Then, when you apply thrust, you change the *velocity*, and remember that applyThrust is only called when the thrust button is pushed, not every frame as the position update is:

```
void Ship::applyThrust()
{
    /* 
       Assume 1 total unit of thrust is applied each time you hit the thrust button
       so you break down the velocity into x and y components depending on the direction
       your ship is facing. 
    */    
    // thrustUnit is how much thrust each thrust button press gets you, it's arbitrary
    // and can be the 2.5 multiplier you're using in your question
    float thrustUnit = 1.0;

    // now get the x and y thrust components of velocity based on your ship's direction
    // assuming 0 degrees is pointing to the right
    float newVX, newVY = 0.0;        
    newVX = thrustUnit * cos(_angle);
    newVY = thrustUnit * sin(_angle); // radian conversion left out to save space

    // Update your ship's velocity
    updateVelocity(newVX, newVY);
}
```

*updateVelocity* will look something like: (note that the velocity is *additive* so it continues to drift unless a thrust is applied in the opposite direction - the same as if it were in a frictionless medium such as space)

```
void Ship::updateVelocity(newVX, newVY)
{
    // update the x component
    velocityX += newVX;
    velocityY += newVY;
}
```

So now you'll also need an updatePosition function that takes into account your ship's velocity.  This gets called with each frame update:

```
void Ship::updatePosition()
{
    // add the x component of velocity to the ship's x position
    // assuming xpos and ypos are variables in the Ship class for tracking position
    xpos += velocityX;
    ypos += velocityY;
}
```

Now the position of the ship changes incrementally according to each velocity component at each frame update.  You can also make *thrustUnit* a member variable to allow for power-ups that can either boost or decrease your thrust component for your ship's speed and being able to control it better with a smaller *thrustUnit* or giving it hyperspeed with a large *thrustUnit*.

Good luck with your game!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm working on that right now.